# Unable to create Jetty WebSocketClient Java org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client;

Tags: java, jetty

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.core.WebSocketComponents.getObjectFactory()" because "this.components" is null
```

when trying to create a WebSocketClient

I have a look at the constructor and it seems like the WebSocketComponents field is set to null for this.coreClient... so of course this will throw a NullPointerException

[Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7xxO.png)

There seems to be no way to set this field? So how am I supposed to use WebSocketClient?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was mixing the jetty client from jetty 12 with jetty 11 .

I simply replaced

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-jetty-client</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

With

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-jetty-client</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```